# Using Roboguice to inject a dependency that does not have a default constructor

Tags: android, roboguice

If I have a class with a single constructor, how can I get Roboguice to inject this into an activity?

The service to be injected:

```
public FlightManager(Context context){
    //do something with the context
}
```

The activity:

```
public class recordFlight extends RoboActivity {

    @InjectResource FlightManager manager;

  //whatever code here
}
```

The only dependency is the Context, which I gather should be injected without problem.  Additoinally, all of my other usages, such as @InjectView and @Inject of classes with a default constructor seem fine, but the usage above kills the app without even giving me a stack trace.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark the constructor with the @Inject annotation:

```
@Inject
public FlightManager(Context context){
    //do something with the context
}
```

Then inject FlightManager like so:

```
public class recordFlight extends RoboActivity {

    @Inject FlightManager manager;

    //whatever code here
}
```

@InjectResource is not necessary here, since it's a regular Java class you're injecting, not an Android resource.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I found out about the @_Inject attribute for the constructor, but completely failed to see the @_InjectResource there - it is strange as I have never tried to inject a resource (only been using Roboguice for an hour!)